# email analytics with smtp2go and phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I used PHPMailer and smtp2go to build a simple function that i can you to send emails , now how can i do analytics on emails , get the emails sent and the emails opened , bounced mails ?

My function is :

```
       require("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php"); 
// path to the PHPMailer class.

function sendmail(){

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
   $mail->Host = "smtpcorp.com"; 
//Enter your SMTP2GO account's SMTP server.

   $mail->Port = "2525"; 
// 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.

   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
// Uncomment this line if you want to use SSL.

   $mail->Username = "";
   $mail->Password = "";

   $mail->From     = "";
   $mail->FromName = "";
   $mail->AddAddress("", "Rachel Recipient");
   $mail->AddReplyTo("", "Sender's Name");

   $mail->Subject  = "Hi!";
   $mail->Body     = "Hi! How are you?";
   $mail->WordWrap = 50;  

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
   } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
   }

}


sendmail();
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Charlie from SMTP2GO.
To access bounces data/reports, you have 3 options:
1) Login to your SMTP2GO control panel, and click on 'Reports > Bounces' where you can view and download past bounces.
2) Use our API.
3) Use our Callbacks functionality (Settings > More > Callbacks).

Please contact us directly from the following page if you'd like any information about the above, and our team will help you out:
http://www.smtp2go.com/support